# MS Access VBA code for making a copy of the old record

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Hi I have two tables AuditSheet2 and Sheet2. I am really new to VBA and so my question is it is possible if the user updates any of the fields in a row of Sheet2 to make a copy of the old record in AuditSheet2.

So for example I have 10 columns in Sheet2 and if the user makes changes in a row to one or even multiple feilds for that record I want just **one record** to be created in the AuditSheet2 table with only the old feilds.

Can someone please help me with this I have searched for weeks and have been unable to figure this out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Access 2010 you can use the After Update Macro. The following MSDN article has an example that is similar to what you desire. It inserts a new record in a comments table. You can start with that example and insert a new record in your audit table using old values instead (via `[Old].[Field Name]`).

[After Update Macro Event on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193905%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Jeremy thanks for the quick response. Do i need to create a data macro named Comments.AddComment because when I run the macro i get an error in the USysApplicationLog table a stating "The data macro 'Comments.AddComment' could not be found."